# Drupal Calendar module and retrieving all dates

Tags: drupal

I guess the calendar wasn't meant to display all dates at once, so I don't know if it is possible.

What I'm doing is using `views_get_view_result()` on my calendar view. But of course, that will only give me the dates for the current month.

I want all the events. Perhaps I can query the database for this content?

Comment: When you say all dates. What do you mean by that? You have 365 dates per year. And unlimited years..

Comment: sorry I meant all events in the calendar.

Comment: Adam, I don't know if this is similar to your need. I'd like to have the calendar module expose a single URL that would contain a master list of all events stored in the calendar (past and present). There would be direct links to all the events, such that a user or crawler wouldn't need to traverse links from day to day then crawl each day's page. There could be a (maybe even unobtrusive) link to that master list somewhere where a crawler might find it without needing to traverse days, months, etc. ("All Events")